# QGIS 3.4.2 not loading .tif files correctly

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I have a surface which has been exported from Civil3D and added to both QGIS 2.18 and 3.4.2

When added they both look very different and the imported image and values in 3.4.2 is not very helpful in that I cannot see what the null values of the image are to remove them.

This cannot be corrected by changing the max. and min. values for the layer either as it just changes the color tone for the whole of the image as if it is all just the one height throughout.

Has anyone else experienced this when adding .tif files to QGIS3.4.2 or is there a new setting somewhere that I have not switched on or set correctly?

View in QGIS 3.4.2: 
[image: View in QGIS 3.4.2]

View in QGIS 2.18.21:
[image: View in QGIS 2.18.21]

Comment: Most probably a bug. Do open a ticket with the QGIS folks. (QGIS 3 is very buggy, sadly).

Comment: Test data would be appreciated.

Comment: The Data for testing has been saved to here:  https://ulster-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/dabkowski-m_ulster_ac_uk/EWlVMhNN-BdAnxtIpxSWhVcBsJFTCFdnEzryABU_jKu8qg?e=rQ5bK1

Comment: It is weird, I opened the image in ArcMap and it did have correct statistics and did display correctly although the bottom half of the non-NODATA area was completely white as in max value.